# Error 1004 when trying to load UserForm with non-blank sheet

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have created a UserForm named `blocksForm` inside a workbook. Buttons inside the form will populate a sheet `BBG` with data from form. I want the form to be able to show even if my `BBG` sheet is not blank and fill in the next blank cell. My form will only load from the command button click when the `BBG` sheet is blank.

When the sheet is not blank and I click the command button to load the form, I get the 1004 error and the debugger highlights `Load blocksForm` from my code

```
Private Sub blocksSorter_Click()
    Load blocksForm
    blocksForm.Show
End Sub
```

I'm assuming the issue might be from my initialize form code below, but I can't pin point it

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Worksheets("DATA")
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("BBG")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    MsgBox (lastRow)

    If Worksheets("BBG").Range("A1") = "" And i < 3 Then
        i = 2
    End If

    activeCheck.Value = False
    itwCheck.Value = False
    yestCheck.Value = False
    recentCheck.Value = False
    TextBox2.Value = ""

    ric = Worksheets("DATA").Range("H" & i)
    name = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B" & i)
    valueUSD = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i)
    adV = Worksheets("DATA").Range("D" & i)
    sitchStr = ""
    dstr = ""
    timeStr = ""

    pStr = ric & "   " & name & "   " & valueUSD & "   " & adV

    Label1.Caption = pStr

    If i > lRow Then
        Unload Me
        Application.Worksheets("BBG").Activate
    End If

End Sub
```

My public variables

```
Public valueUSD, name, ric, adV, dstr, sitchStr, timeStr, pStr As String
Public i, lRow, lastRow, j, k As Long
```

The rest of my code

```
Private Sub activeCheck_Change()

    If activeCheck.Value = True Then
        sitchStr = activeCheck.Caption
        dstr = dstr + sitchStr
    Else
        sitchStr = ""
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub itwCheck_Change()

    If activeCheck.Value = False And itwCheck.Value = True Then
        sitchStr = sitchStr + itwCheck.Caption
        dstr = dstr + sitchStr
    ElseIf activeCheck.Value = True And itwCheck.Value = True Then
        MsgBox ("You can only be active OR ITW")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub yestCheck_Change()

    If yestCheck.Value = True Then
        timeStr = timeStr & " " & yestCheck.Caption
        dstr = dstr + timeStr
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub recentCheck_Change()

    If yestCheck.Value = False And recentCheck.Value = True Then
        timeStr = timeStr & " " & recentCheck.Caption
        dstr = dstr + timeStr
    ElseIf yestCheck.Value = True And recentCheck.Value = True Then
        MsgBox ("You cannot select both yesterday and recently")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_Change()

    If sitchStr = "" Then
        dstr = TextBox2.Value
    ElseIf sitchStr <> "" Then
        dstr = sitchStr & timeStr & ", " & TextBox2.Value
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub addBtn_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set pasteSheet = Application.Worksheets("SHANE FOR BBG")

    If j = 0 Then j = 1

    If Worksheets("BBG").Range("A1") = "" Then
        k = 1
    ElseIf Worksheets("BBG").Range("A1") <> "" Then
        With Worksheets("BBG")
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
        j = lastRow + 2
    End If

    If Not IsError(Application.Match(name, Sheets("BBG").Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        MsgBox ("This is already on your list")
    End If

    pasteSheet.Cells(j, k) = name
    pasteSheet.Cells(j, k + 1) = "(" & ric & ")"
    pasteSheet.Cells(j + 1, k) = valueUSD & ","
    pasteSheet.Cells(j + 1, k + 1) = " " & adV & " ADV"



    If dstr = "" Then
        j = j + 3
    ElseIf dstr <> "" Then
        pasteSheet.Cells(j + 2, k) = dstr
        j = j + 4
    End If

    i = i + 1

    UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub skipBtn_Click()

    If i = 2 Then
        i = 3
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

    UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Private Sub prevBtn_Click()

    i = i - 1
    MsgBox (dstr)
    UserForm_Initialize

End Sub

Sub exitBtn_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Put a break point at the beginning of the Init routine, and step thru it until it kicks you out of the Init routine. That will help you figure out which line is getting the error.

Comment: I get an error right when Im instantiating the variables, breaks when i get to `ric = Worksheets("DATA").Range("H"&i)`

Comment: what is the value of `i` then? Is it 0?

Comment: And keep in mind that this line - `Public i, lRow, lastRow, j, k As Long` defines `k` as a `Long` and all those other variables as `Variant`

Comment: Ah yes MsgBox(i) returned 0. How do I find the last value of i for it to return where it left off in my list?

Comment: do you think I can find the last value in the `BBG` sheet, do something along the lines of a vlookup  of the value to find the last instance of `i`? In my code, `i` represents the row number in the `DATA` sheet.

Comment: It would be best to figure out how `i` is getting set to 0 in the first place, and prevent it. Possibly `prevBtn`? At any rate, this is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Put a break point on every line that changes the value of `i` and follow your logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could include an IF statement to prevent the error, but that wont fix the underlying problem of how `i` got set to `0` in the first place...

```
If i = 0 Then
    Msgbox "Somehow, i got set to zero. Aborting."
    Exit Sub
Else
    ric = Worksheets("DATA").Range("H" & i)
    name = Worksheets("DATA").Range("B" & i)
    valueUSD = Worksheets("DATA").Range("C" & i)
    adV = Worksheets("DATA").Range("D" & i)
End If
```